# Tomcat application issue

Tags: java, linux, bash, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

I have deployed my Java App on server running Tomcat 6. But the app do not respond after almost 15 minutes if it stays idle...i have tried to set -1 in the web.inf of the project as-well as in the web.inf of tomcat but still no effect. But when I log on tomcat moniotr on www.myweb.com:8080 and I click RELOAD, the app starts working fine and again fails after 15 around 15 minutes.

So I think i need some bash script which will check my app status on server after every 15 minutes and if the app is not responding then it reloads the app without restarting the server. Can anyone help me regarding that bash script or cron job?

Comment: I think you need to fix your application not run arbitrary bash scripts. It should be obvious that an application shouldn't fall over after 15 minutes so there is an issue with the application. Attach a debugger to tomcat and see what that issue is then fix it. A bash script or cron job most definitely isn't the way to go.

Comment: I have debugged it as-well and for the time being i am unable to find any major or minor issue. I have also checked catalina.out but there are no exceptions as-well....

Comment: Does it use any resource pools? ( DB Connection pools for example )

Comment: Boris and Cowls you guys are right but the issue is that i need some quick fix to that as this code isn't written by me at all I just put few patches into it. Infact the actual app is also having the same issue which is running on the same server so i can say that this issue isn't caused by my patch lol. So just for a quick fix I am trying to reload the app using some bash script or shifting from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7 or JBoss....

Comment: Yes Dave it does use DB Pools but pools are being managed quite well...

Comment: @ShanAli Next time the app stops responding check the database to see how many connections are open. You can tell if it is a problem with connections not being closed or simply too many being open

Comment: and after 15 minutes i am even unable to see login page.... i mean browser keeps loading it but it never get loaded....

Comment: Restarting the app every 15 mins is such a hack its not something you would want to be associated with. Fixing the root cause is going to be better all round.

Comment: Cowls server is not responding now and i have checked the DB status and its normal.

Comment: What do you mean the status? Have you specifically checked the current open connections?

Comment: yeah you are right cowls but that would take a bit of time which obviously client do not understand lol...

Comment: Yeah cowls SHOW STATUS returned me 1 Aborted_clients, 620 Aborted_connections

Comment: I doubt the client would be too happy having an unstable application either :)

Comment: lol I told him that app fix would take time and he is like NO I NEED A QUICK FIX :)

Comment: 620 aborted connections is not "normal", check this page for some reasons why you are getting those: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/communication-errors.html Note one of them is: "The client program did not call mysql_close() before exiting. "

Comment: Oh let me see it thanks Cowls

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer to the logs of Tomcat. There may be some unhandled exceptions in your app.

Comment: This is not an answer it is a comment. Moreover the OP clearly states _I have also checked catalina.out but there are no exceptions_.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that when I wrote this. Moreover there are other files for different logs in `logs` directory, `catalina.out` is not enough.